# How to implement Lua OOP in my example?

Tags: oop, lua

I am trying to create a class in Lua, which holds information about who is this class following, and I also want followed class to know about his follower.

But my code fails, and I dont know why.

The error is

> lua: OOP.lua:90: attempt to call method 'getName' (a nil value)

```
Vehicle = {}

--------
--FIELDS
--------
Vehicle.name = ""
Vehicle.vtype = "";
Vehicle.follower = {};
Vehicle.leader = {};

---------------------
--SETTERS AND GETTERS
---------------------

function Vehicle:setName(value)
    self.name = value
end
function Vehicle:getName()
    return self.name
end

function Vehicle:setType(value)
    self.vtype = value
end

function Vehicle:getType()
    return self.vtype
end

function Vehicle:setFollower(pVeh)
    self.follower = {};
    self.follower = pVeh;
end;

function Vehicle:getFollower()
    return self.follower;
end;

function Vehicle:getLeader()
    return self.leader;
end;

function Vehicle:setLeader(pVeh)
    self.leader = pVeh;
    if (self.leader ~= nil) then
        print ("-- setted leader! --");
    end;
end;

-----------
--METHODS--
-----------

function Vehicle:follow(pVeh)  --> why does this not work?
    self:setLeader(pVeh);
    pVeh:setFollower(self);
end;


-- constructor
function newVehicle(pNm,pTp)
    tbl = {}
    setmetatable(tbl, {__index = Vehicle});
    tbl:setName(pNm);
    tbl:setType(pTp);
    return tbl
end
```

```
-----------------------------------------------
-- TEST
-----------------------------------------------
local car1 = newVehicle("Mazda","Car");
local car2 = newVehicle("Harley","Bike");
print("--------------");
print (car1:getName()); --> prints "Mazda"
print (car2:getName()); --> prints "Harley"
car2:follow(car1)
print ("Leader of " .. car1:getName() .. " is " .. car1:getLeader():getName())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your test code, from what I can see:

```
print ("Leader of " .. car1:getName() .. " is " .. car1:getLeader():getName())
```

`car1` does not have a leader defined. (you did `car2:follow(car1)`)

Some pointers:

- You need to define field tables in the creation method. This won't apply to your code just yet, but say you wanted to do platoons. You'd do something like `Vehicle.platoon = {}; Tank1.platoon[Tank2] = true` -- This would add Tank2 to Vehicle's platoon table, and share it with every vehicle. If you define this in the new method: `function newVehicle(...)  tbl.platoon = {} ... end`, then it would be unique to every vehicle.
- Don't use accessor (get*, set*) methods unless you have a solid reason for using them. They add clutter, and are not good for performance. A good reason to use them would be if you are accessing a table in your accessor method, and want to simplify the interaction with that. (i.e `Obj:addChild(Obj2)` `obj:hasChild(Obj2)`) But then it probably doesn't qualify as an accessor anymore :)
- You can use dummy objects for unset fields. This'll prevent errors like yours:

  ```
  local Dummy = newVehicle("None", "None")
  Vehicle.follower = Dummy
  Vehicle.leader = Dummy
  ```

In your code, this produces:

```
--------------
Mazda
Harley
-- setted leader! --
Leader of Mazda is None
```

Comment: The error distracted you, it's happened to me before. Be very careful with tables in your `__index`, too, since they are references :)

Answer (score 1):

```
car2:follow(car1)
```

`car1` is **being** *followed* by `car2`. Whereas, later; you're trying to access `car1`'s leader, which, of course returns `nil`. Hence the error.

```
print( "Follower of "..car1:getName().." is "..car1:getFollower():getName() )
```